# Electron Transport Chain Proton Pumping into the Intermembrane Space

Tags: cell-biology, cellular-respiration

In regards to the electron transport chain, I know that complex I pumps 4 H+, complex III pumps 4 H+, and complex IV pumps 2 H+, but where do these numbers come from? If someone could explain this, that would be great. For example, I'm confused at how 4 H+ are pumped when only two enter complex I via NADH + H+.